# shows block files while booting my laptop

Tags: files, 17.04

I got my screen like below while booting up my laptop :

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 273418/30531504 files, 5245319/122096128 blocks
```

Now my question is what this indicates? I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing harmful, it's `fsck` checking your first partition to make sure it's in consistent situation.

Sometimes a forced power off or power failure might be the reason of check disk.